# SOAP Service request without Root Node

Tags: java, apache-camel, soapui, soap-client, spring-ws

Recently i came across a requirement where a SOAP based web service without having a root node has to be consumed.
Below is the request payload which works using **SOAPUI**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ID>123</ID>
        <Currency>USD</Currency>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

`org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransformerException` exception is thrown while passing the above payload to the Apache Camel's ProducerTemplate Body(Which internally leverages on spring-ws).

`org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransformerException: Transformation error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 32; The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.; nested exception is javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 32; The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.`

Would like to get some clarity on below

1. Is it a standard practice to have XML payload without root node?
2. SOAPUI manages to process the request and response and Spring Webservices fails, is it a limitation in Spring WS framework?
3. What is the recommended solution for the same?

Comment: It must have a root node which is a standard.

Comment: @Rao Yes i agree that it should have a root node. The above WSDL is what shared as a service and the same is getting parsed and processed using SOAPUI. I am really unsure how could it manage to do it.

Comment: That is becuase it is wrapped under SOAP BODY.

Comment: If my understanding is right, the request payload under SOAP body should be a well formed XML. Correct me if I am incorrect.

Comment: That's why you getting error. Check with service provider or with your team to resolve the issue.

Comment: it’s provided by a different provider and their point is that as long as it works in SOAPUI its a valid service to be consumed.

Comment: Just as if the message (without SOAP blocks), is being validated against the xml schema definition.

Comment: Yes, and not all SOAP messages are strictly validated against XML schema definition. Its optional!